# Expressing a 'zero-sum' ratio as a point in space? ( Eg. $1:-9:8$ )

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, ratio, spherical-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

I have a collection of ratios (they are all the same degree) where the sum of their parts equate to $0$; and I need a way to represent these ratios as points in space (to perform k-means clustering on them). I can't think of some intuitive relationship between these two ideas.

The simplest approach would be to convert each part into a fraction, and then treat these fractions as the $x,y,z\dots$ components of the point: but this doesn't work for ratios that summate to zero (of which my data is exclusively constructed from)

An idea I had was to use barycentric coordinates, but from what I can tell, this only applies to ratios that consist of positive parts.

Another approach I considered was graphing the ratio as a line with equation $ax=by=cz=\dots$ where the ratio is $a:b:c:\dots$ calculating the intersection with a hemisphere and then treating the intersection as point in (hemi?) spherical space [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziMGw.png) (Hemisphere as there would be two points for a full sphere)

This then turns into a (tessellating?) (hemi?) spherical geometry problem where going below the equator brings you back round to the opposite side [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzds6.png)

Does anyone know any better/simpler/more intuitive methods?

Its also of note that that I plan to apply this method in an arbitrary number number of dimensions (I need to be able to do this for a ratio with any number of parts)

Thanks and I apologise if any terminology is wrong

Comment: Why not simply $(x,y,z)$ in 3d space? Points would all lie on a plane.

Comment: If only ratios matter, you could divide $(x,y,z)$ by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ to get a unit vector: all points will lie on a circle.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca thank you, that seems to work quite nicely